# Rails activeadmin batch actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, activeadmin

```
batch_action :email, form: {message: :textarea} do |ids, inputs|
  batch_action_collection.find(ids).each do |user|
    UserMailer.admin_email(inputs[:message], user.email).deliver_now
  end
end
```

I want the admin to be able to edit the email so I implemented CKeditor in the message textarea. However, I'm having problem getting to show editor in the textarea. I tried doing `{message: :textarea, as: :ckeditor}` but it doesn't work. Any idea?

But, it works fine in the form for e.g. `f.input :description, as: :ckeditor`

Comment: I believe you answer your own question yourself.